# Why does adding an __init__.py change Cython build_ext --inplace behavior?

Tags: cython, setuptools

This is a toy version of a problem I have.  I'm trying to use setuptools to compile some Cython code in place, as part of a larger project.

My topdir is `test`.  It contains:

hello_world.pyx

```
def say_hi():
     print('meh')
```

and setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("hello.pyx"),
)
```

If I build these modules in place with `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`, everything works as expected.

But if add an empty `__init__.py` to my topdir, I get the following error:

```
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/Code/test/hello.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> Code/test
error: could not create 'Code/test/hello.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening?  And is there a standard way of fixing it?  I would like for these compiled Cython modules to live alongside some other C/Python code which is still in development.

Comment: My intuition is that there's a kind of off-by-1 error with regard to which directory I'm in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is happening?

The complete description of what is happening can be found in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3343#issuecomment-1143527672

TL;DR: When you add a `__init__.py` file in your top folder, it interferes with the way Cython computes the extension's name. This results in an incorrect name (incompatible with your project layout due to a missing folder) and causes setuptools to crash.

> And is there a standard way of fixing it?

If you really want to keep the `__init__.py` file under your top-level project folder[^1], you can explicitly use `Extension` objects with the proper/correct name instead of relying on the automatic naming algorithm used by Cython:

```py
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"])]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
)
```

[^1] Please note that this is not common practice in the Python packaging ecosystem.